# How to change the background of ImageView in child view of Expandable ListView at run time

Tags: android, android-listview, parent-child, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have an Expandable listView in which data is populated from Xml file after parsing. My custom Adapter namely NewAdapter populate the content in Expandable list. My problem is arises from **GetChildView()** function where i apply the condition for row that if type is equal to somthing values like 0 or 1 or 2 the at run time the image there in child row should change accordingly. It changed write at first click of group but when i click on second group it shows abnormal behaviour of setting Image. As my Code is following

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
   boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
 {
  tempChild = (ArrayList<String>) Childtem.get(groupPosition);
  Log.d("djdfj", ""+tempChild.size()+"");
  TextView text = null;
  if (convertView == null) 
  {
   convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
  }
  Log.d("check in before if block", ""+sitesList.getResourceType().get(1)+"");
  text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
  img_mediaType = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage1);
  img_status_type =(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.childImage2);
  text.setText(tempChild.get(childPosition));
  if(childPosition==1 && groupPosition==0)
  {
      if(sitesList.getResourceType().get(5).equals("6"))
      {
          Log.d("check in if block",""+sitesList.getResourceType().get(5).equals("6")+"");
          img_mediaType.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
          img_status_type.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.images);
      }
 }
```

and these are my Screenshot this is screen after click group one and group Two[image: this one after click second group]

Hopefully i can describe my question properly it may be not clear but please suggest me how to change image at runtime in Expandable ListView

Comment: Why are you making this Check? `if(childPosition==1 && groupPosition==0)`

Comment: **Mohamed_AbdAllah** actually i want to change image according to my Video type and status type that i got from Array so for testing purpose i checked it. Right image is used for status and left image is used for Type of Video,Audio etc. Can u please suggest me how to change images according to type and status while inflating child row.Any idea will be appreciated

Comment: Try removing the check `groupPosition==0` as I think this will restrict the remaining code to the first group only

Comment: **Mohamed_AbdAllah** if i remove condition it will set image for all row ImageView however i want to set some row image which type is equal to 6